# Python rounds a number, but I want the number to be exact

Tags: python, math

I have written a calculator in python that calculates mean, median, and mode. However, I'm having trouble with the "mean" calculation.
I do the addition, subtraction, and division, but when I print it out, Python rounds the output, instead of giving me the exact number. For example, if I ask it to find the mean of 5 and 6, the answer should be 5.5, but it says it's 5.
Here's the code:

```
print "How many numbers do you wish to use?"
numofnum = input()
print "Now, put in your numbers."
num1 = input()
num2 = input()
sumofnum = num1 + num2
meanans = sumofnum / numofnum
print "Your answer is %f" % (meanans)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are probably using integers and need to use floats instead...

Answer (score 0):

Python's integer division floors the result. You'll have to convert one of your operands to a float type with `float(some_number)`.

Comment: Thanks! This was quite a frustrating problem.

Comment: There are two other possibilities mentioned in the accepted answer for the duplicate: use Python 3, or use `from __future__ import division`.